# Swap ASP.Net Images OnMouseOver event dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create an onmosueover event so that a picture changes from one image to another when I hover the mouse over it. I know how to do this in aspx, I did something like the following:

```
<td style="display: block; width: 320px;" valign="top">
          <img style="margin: 3px; border: 0px solid #000000;" src='/Shop/Images/2.jpg' alt="Robot Kit" width="303px" id="previewImg" />
          <br />
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src='1.jpg' style="width: 70px; border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('previewImg').src='1.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('previewImg').src='2.jpg';" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src='head.jpg' style="width: 70px; border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('previewImg').src='head.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('previewImg').src='2.jpg';" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Now I am trying to make it dynamic and I am pulling the image reference numbers from a Database. I am using the asp:Image tag and so far I have something like the following in my .cs page:

```
  imgItem.ImageUrl = string.Format("Images/{0}.jpg", id);
  imgItem.Width = new Unit(150, UnitType.Pixel);

  imgItem.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:swapImageIn('Shop/Images/3.JPG');return true;");
  imgItem.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "javascript:swapImageOut('imgItem');return true;"); 

  imgItem2.ImageUrl = string.Format("Images/{0}.jpg", 3);
  imgItem2.Width = new Unit(150, UnitType.Pixel);
```

However I am not sure where to take it form here. The code is definitely not complete and I am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend to replace large image with original one when mouse is out? Or leave it as if. Like this - http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Web-API-Security/dp/1430257822/

Comment: Yes I intend to replace the large image with the original one on the mouseout. So it only changes to the image the mouse is hovering on and then back to the original. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lot easier if you use jQuery instead of javascript.

The following code attach both mouseover and mouseout events to images. Then replace an image if a event fires.

You can set `ImageUrl` from code behind if you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container img { width: 100px; }
</style>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".container img").mouseover(function () {
            $("#<%= LargeImage.ClientID %>").attr("src", $(this).prop('src'));
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $("#<%= LargeImage.ClientID %>").attr("src", 
            "http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image1");
    });
});
</script>

<asp:Image ID="LargeImage" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image1" 
    runat="server" />
<div class="container">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image2"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image3"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image3" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image4"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image4" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image5"
        runat="server" />
</div>
```